# Different coloured bottles of two different sizes

Tags: combinatorics

**Question** The table below shows the distribution by colour (green, blue and red) and size (small and large) of a collection of $20$ bottles. All other features of the bottles are exactly the same.

Size $\;$ Green $\;$ Blue$\;$  Red

Small $\;\;$ 4 $\;\;\;\;\;\;$ 5 $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ 6

Large$\;\;\;$  2 $\;\;\;\;\;\;$ 0 $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ 3

These bottles are placed in a random order next to each other on a shelf.

(a) Considering the **small** bottles *only*, in how many different ways can these be placed on the shelf next to each other?

(b) Find the number of all possible different arrangements of all the bottles if the 15 small bottles need to be placed next to each other.

(c) What is the probability that on choosing at random one of the possible arrangements described in (b), a small green bottle is next to a large bottle of a different colour?

**Solution** (a) $\dfrac{15!}{4!5!6!}=630,630$

(b) $6\times\dfrac{15!}{4!5!6!}\times\dfrac{5!}{2!3!}=37,837,800$

(c) Could I have a hint please? Is this part, as follows, correct:

One case would be

[14 small bottles][small G][large R][4 large bottles] (Are there five ways of having similar arrangements?)

There are $\dfrac{14!}{3!5!6!}\times\dfrac{4!}{2!2!}$ ways of the bottles being placed this way.

The other case would be

[4 large][large R][small G][**13 small bottles**][**not** small G]????

Comment: You have the possible cases. I'd begin checking the cases where a small green bottle is in the edge of the array of small bottles. Put a red one next to it and check in how many ways you can sort the rest.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans I am a bit worried about the case where at **each** edge of the small bottles we have a small green bottle, and not to count these kind of arrangements another time in some other case.

Comment: Then count them too and subtract